# Exercising a choice from another choice; self-reference

Tags: daml

I keep on wanting to exercise a choice from another choice (for the same template). Is there a way to do this without knowing the contract id? i.e. I can't call `exercise ??? MyChoice` from the body of another choice, without knowing `???`. Or am I trying to do something fundamentally wrong? Ideally something like `exercise this.id MyChoice`

Answer (score 1):

There is an implicit variable `self` which is the contract ID of `this` given to every choice. So for example,

```
    nonconsuming choice NoConsume : Int
      controller p
      do return 41

    postconsuming choice PostConsume : Int
      controller p
      do (+2) <$> exercise self NoConsume -- Yes, fetching self in a postconsuming choice is ok.
```

Answer (score 0):

From an internal DA conversation:

> moritz.kiefer  9 days ago exercise self MyChoice works iirc?
>
> andrae.muys  9 days ago self was introduced for precisely this
> purpose. Be aware that the contract will be archived before your
> choice exercises in consuming choices. You need to use a
> post-consuming or non-consuming choice to avoid this.
>
> Luciano  9 days
> ago Is postconsuming documented? I don't recall seeing it.
>
> moritz.kiefer  9 days ago
> https://docs.daml.com/concepts/glossary.html#postconsuming-choice
> there is also a blogpost somewhere iirc
>
> moritz.kiefer  9 days ago
> Found it https://blog.daml.com/daml-driven/daml-choice-annotations
> blog.daml.comblog.daml.com DAML choice annotations This post reviews
> the consuming concept and explains the meaning of the newly added
> preconsuming and postconsuming keywords.